# how to activate SSL

Tags: php, apache-2.2, ssl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Apache Virtual Hosts with SSL](https://serverfault.com/questions/48334/apache-virtual-hosts-with-ssl)

How will i activate or enable SSL in my website or web programs. I am using php5 and apache server.

Comment: Do you have root access or are you with shared hosting or managed hosting provider?

Answer (score 0):

In modern Linux, such as for example Ubuntu, it's just

```
sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/mods-available/ssl.* /etc/apache/mods-enabled
```

And then just restart it.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Nothing needed for PHP and webapps, for them SSL is transparent.